# No continuous functions: $ h\left( f\left( x \right)+g\left( y \right) \right)=xy\quad \forall \left( x,y \right)\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{2}} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that there are no continuous functions $f$, $g$ and $h$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
$$
h\left( f\left( x \right)+g\left( y \right) \right)=xy\quad \forall \left( x,y \right)\in {{\mathbb{R}}^{2}}
$$
the starting point of the proof is by contradiction but what next?

Comment: Ya gots ta try somethin'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ and $g$ can't be constant, so $g(\mathbb R)$ has non-empty interior.

Take $y_0 \neq 0$ such that $g(y_0)$ is in the interior of $g(\mathbb R)$ (justification at the end), then
$$h(f(0) + g(y_0)) = 0. $$

Since $g(y_0)$ is in the interior of $g(\mathbb R)$, there is $\epsilon > 0$ s.t.
$[g(y_0) - \epsilon, g(y_0) + \epsilon] \subset g(\mathbb R)$.
$f$ is continuous at $0$, so there is $x_0 \neq 0$ s.t.
$\lvert f(x_0) - f(0)\rvert < \epsilon$.
Therefore $f(0) - f(x_0) + g(y_0) \in g(\mathbb R)$.
Take $y_1$ s.t. $f(0) + g(y_0) = f(x_0) + g(y_1) $.
We have
$$0 = h(f(0) + g(y_0)) = h(f(x_0) + g(y_1)) = x_0 y_1 \neq 0. $$
So such functions $f,g,h$ cannot exist.

---

We can always find $y_0$ such that $g(y_0)$ is in the interior of $g(\mathbb R)$.
If $y_0 = 0$, we can use $g$ being continuous to find $\epsilon' \neq 0$, s.t. $g(\epsilon')$ is in a small neighborhood of $y_0$, contained in $g(\mathbb R)$. So $g(\epsilon')$ is also in the interior.